# How to mine Bitcoin in Windows? How to mine Bitcoin using Intel GPU?

Tags: windows, gpu

I want to mine Bitcoin in Windows, which is the best and trusted software that I can use to mine Bitcoin in Windows? I want to use both my Intel GPU and CPU to mine Bitcoin.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick No

Comment: (1) You cannot mine Bitcoin with a GPU or CPU. That became impossible about a decade ago. See [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/99249/138660) and  aleks1k.github.io/bitcoin-calculator (2) This website is not designed for making software recommendations - you may be able to find some other website for that. See the Help Centre (Click (?) button top right of this page)